# CSS fill horizontal space

Tags: css, html

I've seen a lot of questions about how to make div to fill all available space, but still didn't get it.

### Example

```
<div>
    <div id="div1">    
        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And CSS

```
div { height:100px; }
#div1 { width: 100%; }
#div2 { background-color:blue; float:left; width:30%; }
#div3 { background-color:green; float:left; }
```

I want green `#div3` block to fill all horizontal space, but upper CSS doesn't work - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEJvS/1/).

I'm not setting `width` manually as you can see. Even if I write `width: auto;` it won't work.

Comment: Is `float: aleft;` a typo *here* or in your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions.

### Solution 1

set concrete `width` (not `auto`) to green element because it's floated.

### Solution 2

Don't float your green element. Depending whether you want your green element to wrap underneath blue one (when higher) set left margin appropriately.

```
margin-left: 30%; /* should always be right of the blue */
```

You can set other margins however you like.

### Margins on green `div`

I don't know whether you allow your green to expand under blue `div` when its height gets higher than the blue one. But suppose you want to keep it right to the blue `div`.

Not floating green should make this most simple, because you can manipulate green's dimensions to you own liking. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NEJvS/19/) that shows green `div` that is higher than blue, doesn't wrap under blue and has a fixed right margin set in pixels. **Works**.

You can also add additional padding or borders on green element and it will still work.

#### Example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXFcm/)

This example floats left `div` and keeps right green `div` always to the right of it whie also adding some space between them. It uses CSS3 `calc()` function that is supported as per following [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/calc) data.

As you can see I've also heavily simplified your HTML:

```
<div class="left">Nav</div>
<div class="right">Content</div>​
```

CSS includes additional browser-specific settings for `calc` usage, but in the future they will become obsolete and only last setting for `margin-left` will be used by browsers.

```
.left {
    background-color: #69c;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
.right {
    background-color: #9c9;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: -webkit-calc(30% + 10px);
    margin-left: -moz-calc(30% + 10px);
    margin-left: calc(30% + 10px);
}
```

Comment: And if green block has `margin-right:20px` and I set `width:70%` it will go under the blue block. I don't really want to pick width percentage (69 or 68...) because of variety of resolutions.

Comment: @ChruS: If you don't want it to get under the blue then unfloat it and set left margin to 30%. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NEJvS/19/).

Comment: Looks like the only possible solution. One more thing: if blue block has `margin-left: 20px` also, how can I set left margin on green block to have always the same fixed space between blocks?

Comment: @ChruS: Which browsers do you have to support? IE9+ and latest webkit (Chrome, Safari) and FF? If that is the case then you can easily set left margin on green to `calc(30% + 20px)`. http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: @ChruS: Great! Then I suggest you simply do that. `calc` is used to combine different dimensions. But make sure you provide browser specific versions (compatibility reasons as of now) i.e. `-webkit-calc()`... http://jsfiddle.net/LXFcm/

Answer (score 0):

You need to [setup](http://jsfiddle.net/NEJvS/11/) BG color for parent div

```
  #div1 { width: 100%;background-color:green; }
```

if you want to do with div3 then give width to that [div](http://jsfiddle.net/NEJvS/18/)

```
#div3 { background-color:green; float:left; width: 70%; }
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I need exactly `div3` to fill the space.

Comment: @ChruS check now with adding width 70% to div3

Comment: Yes this helps, but what about margins?

Answer (score 0):

If you want what i think you want... set width:100% to div and width:70% to div3.

if it's not what you wanted be a little more specific